# I can't run test with "vows test/*" command on windows. How to use it? node.js

Tags: node.js, testing, vows

I've installed vows as module of my project and I've added the path "node_modules\vows\bin" to my environment path variable of windows vista.

**note:** I've also renamed "node_modules\vows\bin\vows" to vows.exe, because without the extension I get this error: 'vows' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Now wherever I put "vows" in my cmd in windows nothing happens, I cd into my test folder and I run "vows myFirstTest.js" and nothing happens. (when I say nothing happens my cursor in cmd is going to the top and then return to it's original position and it's doing this forever, therefore each time I try a vows command in cmd I have to close the cmd to run another command).

What I'm doing bad?

thanks

Comment: I think you should install vows globally `npm install -g vows` instead of modifying the PATH var yourself.

Comment: what the ...? that worked!!. Thanks, put it in an answer and I will accept it ;)

Comment: but the "vows test/*" doesnt work now. I get this error: module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'"); but If I run it individually "vows mytest.js" it works as expected.

Comment: if I go to my root folder and I run "vows" it says "Could not find any tests to run.". If I go into my "test" folder and run "vows" says: "vows runner couldn't find test folder
vows runner exiting". If in my "test" folder I run "vows insertWorker.js" it runs one test. what's the problem?

Comment: solved: https://github.com/cloudhead/vows/issues/57; my test files were missing the -test in their filename. A filename like "mytest.js" doesn't work. It must be "mytest-test.js" in order to work.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked, posted the answer so you can mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NPM is great at globally installing packages and making the executable for each operating system (UNIX-ish + Windows), so proceed with the following:

```
npm install -g vows
```